# Prove for all real numbers $a, \ b,$ and $c$, $bc + ac + ab \leq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I've been having some trouble with this particular problem. Could someone provide a hint of some sort? My original attempt that turned out to be useless is to start off with
$$(b+c)^2 + (a+c)^2 + (a+b)^2 = (b+c)^2 + (a+c)^2 + (a+b)^2$$
and subtract from both sides until I get the above inequality, but I found out I'd end up subtracting that very same inequality and would be right back where I started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIG HINT:
$$2a^2+2b^2+2c^2\geq 2ab+2bc+2ac\\a^2+b^2+b^2+c^2+a^2+c^2\geq 2ab+2bc+2ac$$

Comment: HINT? No BIG HINT! haha

Comment: Question - as long as you show a statement implies something that is universally correct, then the statement itself is correct?

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek You would need to reverse the order; show that something which is universally correct implies your statement,or that those two statements are equivalent.Because something false can imply something true.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was wondering that regarding the other answer, but I appreciate you clearing up my confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

$
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca\\
\Longleftrightarrow \frac12(2a^2 + 2b^2 + 2c^2 - 2ab - 2bc - 2ca) \ge 0\\
\Longleftrightarrow (a^2 - 2ab + b^2) + (b^2 - 2bc + c^2) + (c^2 - 2ac + a^2) \ge 0 \\
\Longleftrightarrow (a-b)^2 +(b-c)^2 +(c-a)^2 \ge 0
$

which is obviously true. Giving a hint for this problem is as good as solving it entirely. :-)

Comment: Hey maybe you should've used $\iff$ instead of $\implies$ because something false can imply something true.

Comment: @kingW3, noted. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

внимание: overkill. Stating that for any $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we have
$$ Q(a,b,c) = a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc \geq 0 \tag{1}$$
is the same as stating that the following symmetric matrix
$$ Q = \begin{pmatrix}1& -\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&1&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}& 1\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$
is positive semi-definite. That is simple to prove through Sylvester's criterion (the determinants of the principal minors are $\geq 0$) or by computing the eigenvalues of $Q$, namely $\left\{0,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right\}$.